# Placing images in a twitter bootstrap's grid

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Need to place images kinda like here (for example): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD4GD.jpg
Original pictures of different sizes. 
Hover effect - blur and fogging effects and text on the middle of the picture.
Here is what I got for now: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12787/)

So the question, how correctly position them, so that they occupy the entire width of the screen by 3 in a row, gonna be same size, closely adhering to the upper and lower `div` and to each other, don't expand within its borders? And the effect of the blur doesn't touch neighboring elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this css, you'll get the look like the example --

```
.works img{
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
}

.works [class^="col-"] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.works .text{
    position:absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works great! But I don't get, how to fix that space under the rows of images. Mean these: http://i.imgur.com/Eot9A81.jpg

Comment: If you have it live, give me the link

Comment: Its seen on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12787/) if zoom out a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Remove class row and col-lg-12,use col-sm-12 like

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="work1" class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="image" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03257/POTD-SKY-SQUIRREL_3257854k.jpg">
                    <p class="text">ONE</p>
                </div>
                <div id="work2" class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="image" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03235/potd-husky_3235255k.jpg">
                    <p class="text">TWO</p>
                </div>
                <div id="work3" class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="image" src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/dolphin-pictures-1.jpg">
                    <p class="text">THREE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
works img {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;}
```